# Сравнение элементов двумерного массива и вывод количества строк, в которых есть повторяющиеся элементы

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Как я понимаю, это ниже приведено сравнение рядом стоящих элементов.
А как сделать, чтобы сравнивались все элементы в строке - каждый с каждым?

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j]==arr[i][j+1]) b=b+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ещё один вложенный цикл k от j+1 до n
arr[i][j]==arr[i][k]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так устроит?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)               // В каждой строке
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)           // Каждый элемент
    {
        for (k = j+1; k < n; k++)     // со всеми, которые правее...
        {
            if (arr[i][j]==arr[i][k]) ........;
        }
    }
}
```

Только учтите, что, например, в строе

```
1  2  3  1  4  5  1  6  7  1
```

Вы обнаружите совпадения первой единицы с тремя, второй - с двумя, и третьей - с одной, итого 6 (шесть) раз!

Для определения количества строк я бы делал так:

```
int count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        for (k = j+1; k < n; k++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j]==arr[i][k])
            {
                ++count;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) break;
    }
}
```

Т.е. при первом же совпадении выходил из внутренних циклов (для этого нужне переменная `found` - если нашли хоть одно совпадение - дальше проверять смысла нет!). Количество строк с наличием *повторяющихся в пределах строки* элементами - в `count`.

Comment: А чтобы посчитать сколько будет строк(в которых хотя бы есть 1 совпадение) нужна новая переменная?

Comment: А, я не глянул... вам же надо только количество СТРОК, а не в строках... Подождите, сейчас дополню ответ...

Comment: Cпасибо огромное! Очень выручили!

Comment: Ну, если устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, пометив ответ как принятый...